# tkz-euclide: How to modify the arrows of \tkzShowPointCoord?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I don't like the default arrow heads of `\tkzShowPointCoord`. How can I change them?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,1/0/I,0/1/J}
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,>=latex]
\tkzDefPoint(3,4){A}
\tkzDrawPoints(O,A)
\tkzLabelPoint(A){$A_1 (x_1,y_1)$}
\tkzShowPointCoord[xlabel=$x_1$,
ylabel=$y_1$](A)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,I)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](J)
\tkzDrawPoints[shape=cross](I,J)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kind of have the answer in your code already: `>={insert arrow tip specification}`. You can use that in the options to `\tkzShowPointCoord`.

If you also add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` you have access to a lot of different arrow tips, which are also customizable. Hence, you could do something like

```
\tkzShowPointCoord[xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$y_1$,>={Kite[red,width=1cm,length=2cm]}](A)
```

for some rather inconspicuous arrow tips:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,1/0/I,0/1/J}
\tkzDrawXY[noticks]
\tkzDefPoint(3,4){A}
\tkzDrawPoints(O,A)
\tkzLabelPoint(A){$A_1 (x_1,y_1)$}
\tkzShowPointCoord[xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$y_1$,>={Kite[red,width=1cm,length=2cm]}](A)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,I)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](J)
\tkzDrawPoints[shape=cross](I,J)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```